# Why is the value not set to null each time this function is called?

Tags: javascript, throttling

Can someone explain to me why lastEventTimestamp isn't reset to null each time a function is called?

```
Function.prototype.throttle = function (milliseconds, context) {
    var baseFunction = this,
        lastEventTimestamp = null,
        limit = milliseconds;

    return function () {
        var self = context || this,
            args = arguments,
            now = Date.now();

        if (!lastEventTimestamp || now - lastEventTimestamp >= limit) {
            lastEventTimestamp = now;
            baseFunction.apply(self, args);
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: *a function is called*: which function? Please show the code that produces the result you did not expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call *throttle* a new closure is created in which *lastEventTimestamp* is defined as `null`. The inner function has a reference to that variable, so when that function is returned, the closure still has a reference to it, and keeps its state:

```
function test() {
}

var myTest = test.throttle(100);

myTest();
myTest();
```

When you then call the function *myTest* -- that was returned -- repeatedly, it will act on the same instance of that *lastEventTimestamp* variable. Note that calling that function will not execute the assignment `lastEventTimestamp = null`, but only the code in that inner function body. So indeed there is no reason why that variable should be reset. It keeps its state between calls. This is the [power of closures in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

See which `console.log` calls are executed in this snippet:

```js
Function.prototype.throttle = function (milliseconds, context) {
    console.log('initialising throttle');
    var baseFunction = this,
        lastEventTimestamp = null,
        limit = milliseconds;

    return function () {
        console.log('running throttle wrapper function');
        var self = context || this,
            args = arguments,
            now = Date.now();

        if (!lastEventTimestamp || now - lastEventTimestamp >= limit) {
            lastEventTimestamp = now;
            console.log('calling original function');
            baseFunction.apply(self, args);
        }
    };
};

function test() {
    console.log('running test');
}

var myTest = test.throttle(100);

myTest();
myTest(); // runs too soon, so test is not called.
```

Note how `'running throttle wrapper function'` only appears once in the output.

Comment: Thank you very much, that link you included helped a lot, especially Example 7. My lack of knowledge about closures had lead to my confusion. Thanks again!